# Problem with JS linked to an Ajax loaded page

Tags: 7, ajax

I am trying to load a form via ajax, the PHP callback that send the data to the Ajax request looks like this :

```
function group_form (){

        $node_type = 'group';
        $form_id = $node_type . '_node_form';     
        $node = new stdClass();
        $node->type = $node_type;
        $node->title = 'helllooo';
        $node->language = LANGUAGE_NONE;
        $node->path = '';
        node_object_prepare($node);
        $return=drupal_get_form($form_id,$node);

    echo render($return);
}
```

I use to have a problem when using `return` instead of `echo` as mentioned in this [Q](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/9961/loading-a-form-via-ajax-with-drupal-get-form), where the whole page was being sent via Ajax instead of just the form element. However now that i use `echo` all the script attached to that form do not get reloaded, witch cause problem as my form uses the date module with a jQuery popup calender, and infinite value fields witch need some Drupal JS in order to add multiple values without page reload.

So i wonder if there is a way around that, if not, anyone has anyidea of what script i should reload on the ajax succes callback in order to have my date module popup calendar and the drupal "Add more" function for infinite value field working ?

**EDIT:** I found that using `Drupal.attachBehaviors(jQuery('#LoadedContent'));` seems to be helping as it brings me from this [image]

---

to this [image],

---

though clicking on the "Add another item" Button still reload the page and i end up with this : [image]

Thanks a bunch for the help.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at the [Ajax Framework](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21ajax.inc/7.x). It will make your life way easier. You can probably accomplish everything you're trying to do with out a single line of js.

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass the JS settings that are created when the form is rendered:

```
function group_form (){

  $node_type = 'group';
  $form_id = $node_type . '_node_form';     
  $node = new stdClass();
  $node->type = $node_type
  $node->title = 'helllooo';
  $node->language = LANGUAGE_NONE;
  $node->path = '';
  node_object_prepare($node);
  $form = drupal_get_form($form_id,$node);

  $response = render($form);

  $scripts = drupal_add_js();
  if (!empty($scripts['settings']))
  {
    $settings = '<script type="text/javascript">jQuery.extend(Drupal.settings, ';
    $settings .= drupal_json_encode(call_user_func_array('array_merge_recursive', $scripts['settings']['data']));
    $settings .= ');</script>';
  }

  $response .= $settings;

  echo $response;
  drupal_exit();
}
```

Though personally I'd put the response in an array. So instead of this:

```
$response = render($form);

$scripts = drupal_add_js();
if (!empty($scripts['settings']))
{
  $settings = '<script type="text/javascript">jQuery.extend(Drupal.settings, ';
  $settings .= drupal_json_encode(call_user_func_array('array_merge_recursive', $scripts['settings']['data']));
  $settings .= ');</script>';
}

$response .= $settings;

echo $response;
drupal_exit();
```

I'd use this:

```
$response['form'] = render($form);

$scripts = drupal_add_js();
if (!empty($scripts['settings']))
{
  $settings = '<script type="text/javascript">jQuery.extend(Drupal.settings, ';
  $settings .= drupal_json_encode(call_user_func_array('array_merge_recursive', $scripts['settings']['data']));
  $settings .= ');</script>';
}

$response['form'] .= $settings;

drupal_json_output($response);
drupal_exit();
```

Your form will be available at data.form in the ajax.

You will also need to call the following after injecting your form into the page:

```
Drupal.attachBehaviors();
```